# Validation error not falling after using multiple techniques to lower

Tags: python, tensorflow, validation, machine-learning

I have been trying to reduce the amount of validation error I am getting in a CNN that I am training. I have a tried various methods such as l1 and l2 regularization, dropout, gaussian noise, and reshaping the CNN network. However, the validation error never drops below 0.5, which is a too high for my application (I need it closer to 0.1 or 0.2). Below is a copy of the CNN without any methods to reduce validation error:

```html
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Reshape((20, 60, 3)))

    model.add(Conv2D(24, (5, 5), input_shape=(20, 60, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(36, (5, 5),activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(48, (5, 5),  activation='elu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu', bias_regularizer=l1(0.09)))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'elu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(Adam(lr = 0.0001, decay=1e-6), loss='mse', metrics = ['mae'])

<!-- end snippet -->


    Epoch 1/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 35.1210 - mae: 4.9702 - val_loss: 1.8467 - val_mae: 1.0457
    Epoch 2/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 1.4348 - mae: 0.9413 - val_loss: 1.0911 - val_mae: 0.8573
    Epoch 3/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 1.1180 - mae: 0.8686 - val_loss: 1.1062 - val_mae: 0.8561
    Epoch 4/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.9902 - mae: 0.8055 - val_loss: 0.9725 - val_mae: 0.8031
    Epoch 5/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.8890 - mae: 0.7571 - val_loss: 0.8132 - val_mae: 0.7385
    Epoch 6/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7439 - mae: 0.6985 - val_loss: 0.8021 - val_mae: 0.7304
    Epoch 7/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7172 - mae: 0.6676 - val_loss: 0.7327 - val_mae: 0.6954
    Epoch 8/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6808 - mae: 0.6522 - val_loss: 0.6892 - val_mae: 0.6690
    Epoch 9/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6084 - mae: 0.6209 - 

[...Continues training ...]

 val_loss: 0.5327 - val_mae: 0.5292
    Epoch 479/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0407 - mae: 0.1361 - val_loss: 0.5249 - val_mae: 0.5315
    Epoch 480/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0320 - mae: 0.1203 - val_loss: 0.5199 - val_mae: 0.5223
    Epoch 481/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0334 - mae: 0.1199 - val_loss: 0.5439 - val_mae: 0.5354
    Epoch 482/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0368 - mae: 0.1300 - val_loss: 0.5356 - val_mae: 0.5373
    Epoch 483/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0493 - mae: 0.1555 - val_loss: 0.5455 - val_mae: 0.5430
    Epoch 484/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0380 - mae: 0.1315 - val_loss: 0.5240 - val_mae: 0.5278
    Epoch 485/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0364 - mae: 0.1320 - val_loss: 0.5132 - val_mae: 0.5233
    Epoch 486/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0388 - mae: 0.1309 - val_loss: 0.5558 - val_mae: 0.5499
    Epoch 487/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0386 - mae: 0.1369 - val_loss: 0.5442 - val_mae: 0.5376
    Epoch 488/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0347 - mae: 0.1269 - val_loss: 0.5334 - val_mae: 0.5344
    Epoch 489/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0393 - mae: 0.1368 - val_loss: 0.5507 - val_mae: 0.5383
    Epoch 490/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0348 - mae: 0.1307 - val_loss: 0.5382 - val_mae: 0.5337
    Epoch 491/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0341 - mae: 0.1253 - val_loss: 0.5301 - val_mae: 0.5367
    Epoch 492/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0359 - mae: 0.1342 - val_loss: 0.5293 - val_mae: 0.5317
    Epoch 493/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0360 - mae: 0.1325 - val_loss: 0.5434 - val_mae: 0.5443
    Epoch 494/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0339 - mae: 0.1275 - val_loss: 0.5341 - val_mae: 0.5305
    Epoch 495/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0358 - mae: 0.1252 - val_loss: 0.5621 - val_mae: 0.5478
    Epoch 496/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0379 - mae: 0.1341 - val_loss: 0.5228 - val_mae: 0.5293
    Epoch 497/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0297 - mae: 0.1174 - val_loss: 0.5345 - val_mae: 0.5335
    Epoch 498/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0328 - mae: 0.1252 - val_loss: 0.5492 - val_mae: 0.5454
    Epoch 499/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0361 - mae: 0.1332 - val_loss: 0.5421 - val_mae: 0.5382
    Epoch 500/500
    84/84 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0294 - mae: 0.1182 - val_loss: 0.5354 - val_mae: 0.5380
```

How could I possibly decrease validation error and what may be some reasons that the other techniques not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your `val_loss` at epoch 500, you will see that his value is 0.5354, whereas training loss is 0.0294. It's almost 20 times bigger. Moreover, if you only focus in `val_loss`, you will see that from epoch 8 (0.6892) to epoch 500 (0.5354) you make a super small improvement. So you can say you are **overfitting**.

To avoid this, you should obtain super similar values of val between training and validation.

Typical steps to avoid overfitting:

- Use more data for training (I don't know if it's possible in you case)
- Increase the complexity of the CNN (more layers and more neurons per layer)
- Use extra techniques (as you already used: dropout, regularization,..)
- Reduce the learning rate (even more)

Probably your are not achieving results after applying you techniques because you are not avoiding the overfitting. It seems that your networks is too simple or that you have only a few data.